# What happens if I do printf("one\0two");?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printf

As implied by the title, what's meant to get printed if I do this in C++:

```
printf("one\0two");
```

? GCC gives me a warning when I do this, but visual studio is fine with it. Do they work differently at all? Thinking about it, I'd expect printf to stop at the first \0, but apparently the code that uses this has been working fine on windows until now, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll get:

```
$ a.out
one$
```

the `\0` is a null and ends the string.  No newline.

```
$ cat try.c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(){
    printf("one\0two");
    return 0;
}
542 $ gcc try.c
try.c: In function ‘main’:
try.c:5: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format
543 $ ./a.out
one544 $
```

Answer (score 5):

C-style strings are null terminated.  So when printing a string, it will print everything up to the first occurrence of a null character.  In that case, it should print `one` and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

You get 'one' printed - with no newline after it.

You also get compiler warnings.

GCC is being kind - letting you know that the 'two' is irrelevant.  <s>You also should not use</s> There is little point in using `printf()` with a format string with no `%` marks in it...you could use `puts()` or `fputs()` instead.  And it is crucial for security reasons not to use a format string that the user can choose:  `char *s = ...; printf(s);`.

MSVS is not wrong in not giving you the warning; the compiler is not obliged to suggest ways to fix your code.

Comment: "You also should not use printf() with a format string with no % marks in it": That's a new one on me! Why on earth not? I do it all the time. Perhaps you mean that you shouldn't use `printf (s)` to print an arbitrary string (that may contain % marks)? That I agree with.

Comment: @TonyK: at one time, one of the GCC compilers produced warnings, I thought, for that.  However, it is not 4.6.0, 4.5.x or 4.2.1 - the versions I have on hand.  I must be misremembering...though there is some justice to the observation that there's not a lot of point in using `printf()` with a plain string.  I'll fix the comment.  (Format string vulnerabilities induced by `printf(s)` where `s` is a user-controlled string are a much more serious problem - as you stated.)

Answer (score 2):

`printf` will indeed stop at the embedded "null" character, and just print "one".

GCC gives a warning, because there's a good chance that a format string like this is wrong; it will also compare the format string with the argument types and give warnings if they don't match. Other compilers don't put so much effort into analysing the arguments of functions like `printf` and will let dodgy arguments through with no warnings.